# How to sum a column in rshiny, rhandsontable

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I'm trying to get the sum of a column in rhandsontable within an rshiny. I found a similar solutions to multiply to columns, and I was able to modify it slightly. However, when I run the shiny, the cell that is supposed to be summing starts counting without any inputs and just runs on. I'm including a simplified example of what I am trying to do and what is happening.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

## Create the dataset
DF = data.frame(num = 1:10, price = 1:10,Total = 1:10,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
numberofrows <- nrow(DF)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Initiate your table
  previous <- reactive({DF})
  
  MyChanges <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$hotable1)){return(previous())}
    else if(!identical(previous(),input$hotable1)){
      # hot.to.df function will convert your updated table into the dataframe
      mytable <- as.data.frame(hot_to_r(input$hotable1))

      mytable[,1][is.na(mytable[,1])] <- 0
      mytable[,2][is.na(mytable[,2])] <- 0
      mytable[11,1] <- sum(as.numeric(mytable[,1]))
      mytable
    }
  })
  output$hotable1 <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(MyChanges())})
})

ui <- basicPage(mainPanel(rHandsontableOutput("hotable1")))
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I thought that simply using the sum function would only sum when changes are made. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to Stack Exchange but this seems like a good question to me! Not sure why so few views. Anyhow, below is a solution. One important change is I also sum the column on the far right for "Total", in addition to the bottom row which sums all columns. I added explanatory comments too.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

# change DF formation from OP to separate out column and row names, for tabulation in observer:
rowNames <- c(1:11)
colNames <- c("num","price","Total")
DF = data.frame(row.names = rowNames, c(1:10,55), c(1:10,55),c(seq(2,20,2),65))
colnames(DF) <- colNames
numberofrows <- nrow(DF)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  previous <- reactiveVal(DF)
  
  observeEvent(input$hotable1,{previous(hot_to_r(input$hotable1))}) # reflects user inputs into table
  
  output$hotable1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(previous(), useTypes = TRUE) %>%
      hot_row(c(11), readOnly = TRUE) %>%   # block user inputs into total row
      hot_col(c("Total"), readOnly = TRUE)  # block user inputs into total column
  })
  
  # this observes any user inputs into the table for recalculating row and column totals:  
  observe({
    req(input$hotable1)
    tmp <- hot_to_r(input$hotable1)
    tmp[11,] <- colSums(tmp[setdiff(rowNames, 11),], na.rm = TRUE)         # total columns
    tmp[,"Total"] <- rowSums(tmp[setdiff(colNames,"Total")], na.rm = TRUE) # total rows
    previous(tmp)
  })

})    

ui <- basicPage(mainPanel(rHandsontableOutput("hotable1")))
shinyApp(ui, server)
```